# Proving differentiability at an end point.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

So i have this question:

$f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, differentiable on $(a,b)$ and $\lim_{x\to a^+}f'(x) = L$.
I need to show $f$ is differentiable at $a$ and $f'(a) = L$.

So we've been doing the Mean Value Theorem, but i can't see how that would apply here, so i have tried to use the definition of a derivative to show the function is differentiable at a, but can't seem to get anywhere!
Anyone got any hints?
Thanks :)

Comment: The limit of what is $L$?

Answer (score 2):

For any $\epsilon>0$, there is a $\delta>0$ that for any $a<x<a+\delta$, $\:|f'(x)-L|<\epsilon$. Now for any $a<y<a+\delta$, by MVT, there is $a<x<y$ that $f(y)-f(a)=f'(x)(y-a)$. So
$$
\left|\frac{f(y)-f(a)}{y-a}-L\right|=|f'(x)-L|<\epsilon
$$
Thus
$$
\varlimsup_{y\to a^+}\left|\frac{f(y)-f(a)}{y-a}-L\right|\leqslant\epsilon\quad\text{}\quad 
$$
Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary small, there is
$$
\varlimsup_{y\to a^+}\left|\frac{f(y)-f(a)}{y-a}-L\right|=0
$$
Since lower limit is always non negative and less than upper limit, this means 
$$
\varlimsup_{y\to a^+}\left|\frac{f(y)-f(a)}{y-a}-L\right|=\varliminf_{y\to a^+}\left|\frac{f(y)-f(a)}{y-a}-L\right|
$$
So we have
$$
\lim_{y\to a^+}\frac{f(y)-f(a)}{y-a}=L\quad\text{and }\quad \lim_{y\to a^+}f'(y)=f'(a)=L
$$

Comment: sorry it should've been the limit of the derivative not the function

Comment: thanks! this really helped